# Не передается модель

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Код представления:

```
@{
Layout = null;
 }@model string
 @Html.Raw(Model)
```

Код действия контроллера:

```
  public ViewResult PageView()
    {
          string  s = "<div>text</div>";

        return View("Index",s);
    }
```

Когда запускаю действие - получаю ошибку "путь содержит недопустимые символы". В чем может быть загвоздка ? Как я понимаю, обработчик ищет представление по имени s, но не воспринимает s как модель.

Comment: У вас представление точно Index? В самом коде представления я нигде не вижу вывода S переменной

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите передать модель с типом строки тогда необходимо воспользоваться такой конструкцией:

```
public ViewResult PageView()
{
    string  s = "<div>text</div>";
    return View("Index",null,s);
}
```